QGIS 3.38.2 Grenoble gdal2tiles output tiles in JPEG format instead of PNG
I'm using the gdal2tiles processing toolbox within QGIS 3.38.2 with GDAL version 3.9.2 and Python 3.12.5 but don't see any way to create JPEG tiles as an output option. It only defaults to output of PNG files/tiles.
Looking at the documentation on GDAL as of version 3.6 gdal2tiles says it support JPEG using the --tiledriver=JPEG option.
https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal2tiles-tiledriver
Will QGIS have a way to use this option also?

The support for JPEG output in gdal2tiles was introduced in GDAL 3.9.0 (released only about 3 months ago) https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.9.0/NEWS.md.
The corresponding QGIS processing algorithm has not yet been updated in order to support the JPEG output (and the WEBP output too).
You need to file a Feature request at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new/choose if you want the support for JPEG output to be available in the QGIS processing algorithm.
